# Can lower-ranked personnel refuse promotions?

Tags: star-trek, starfleet-rank

Commander Riker refused his own command (and, by extension, a promotion) a few times during TNG's run. Captain Picard rejected Admiral Quinn's attempt to have him promoted to admiral.

If a lowly ensign or lieutenant were to be promoted due to excellent service, could they reject the offer and stay where they are?

Comment: Why not? Seems fairly clear serving in Starfleet is effectively a hobby in the first place (the Federation being post-scarcity society with all basic needs provided for and all). Seems like you wouldn't *want* to hand additional responsibilities to someone who is not willing to accept them.

Comment: I don't think any modern (or future) military organisation would force a promotion on an unwilling person, that would be disastrous for morale and the command structure. The exception being field promotion, where a junior must take command when a senior officer is killed or incapacitated. As a side note my grandfather was promoted from corporal to sergeant in the British Army several times and turned it down each time as he didn't want the added responsibility.

Comment: Not only can you, but unlike contemporary militaries, you can essentially resign at any time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, O'Brien discusses putting in for a transfer. Since he's been promoted in his current role, changing position would result in him taking a diminished rank.

> **O'BRIEN:** *Look, I'm willing to ask for a transfer if that'll make you happy.*
>
> **KEIKO:** *That's not fair either. **You'd have to give up your promotion.***
>
> **O'BRIEN:** *Not necessarily.*
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: A Man Alone](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/403.htm)</sup></sub>

Moving down the canon scale, it's discussed in one of the TNG novels that married Starfleet couples are often forced to turn down promotions in order to remain together.

> Nor could they have chosen a better time for it. In the past,
> Starfleet marriages were risky endeavors, often doomed in the attempt
> to balance two careers, **forcing choices between refused promotions or
> long separations.** Either way, domestic pressures added to an already
> stressful lifestyle resulted in an unconscionably high rate of broken
> marriages.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek TNG: Survivors](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Survivors)</sup></sub>

Comment: By the way, to add onto this answer...https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/how-many-promotions-did-riker-turn-down?rq=1

Comment: @IrwinAllen13 - OP was asking about lower ranked officers, not command rankings.

Comment: True, but the Command ranks are held to a higher standard. He is setting an example for everyone in Starfleet. And since, not too many people make it a HUGE deal (i.e. it's not breaking news across the galaxy), one could safely assume that this actually happens on a common occurrence.

Comment: @IrwinAllen13 - Oh sure. In the show and books we see multiple occasions where command officers turn down various promotions to Captaincies and Admiralships (notably Picard, Riker (*repeatedly*), Sisko, Spock and Tuvok). But that's not what the question was asking